# How to implement the function delete of a binary search tree without recursion in C?

Tags: c

I try to implement the delete method but that doesn't work with me. [I want to delete all nodes in the tree.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48000768/how-to-implement#comment82970456_48000768) The function has tree type of "struct tree" as a parameter so I can't use recursion; I want to do it with a loop.

That's my structure

```
    typedef struct Node Node;
    struct Node{
        const void* data;
        const void* value; 
        Node* left;
        Node* right;
    };

    typedef struct Tree Tree;
    struct Tree{
        Node* root;
        size_t size;
        int (*comp)(const void *, const void *);
    };
```

function delete

```
    void freeTree(Tree* tree, bool TreeContent){
        if(tree->root != NULL){

            // free(tree->root->left);
            // free(tree->root->right);
            // free(tree->root);
        }
    }
```

function insert

```
bool insertInTree(Tree* bst, const void* key, const void* value){
    if(bst->root == NULL){
            Node* newNode = (Node*) malloc(sizeof(Node));
            if(newNode == NULL){
                   printf("erreur d'allocation dynamique \n");
                   exit(1);
            }
            newNode->left =  newNode->right = NULL;
            newNode->value = value;
            newNode->data = key;
            return true;
    }
    else{
            int isLeft = 0 ;
            Node* Current = bst->root ;
            Node* precedant = NULL;
            while(Current != NULL){
                int compare = bst->comp(&Current->data , &key);
                precedant = Current;
            if(compare == 1){
                   isLeft = 1;
                   Current = Current->left;
            }
            else if(compare == 0){
                    isLeft = 0;
                    Current = Current->right;
            }

            }
            if(isLeft == 1){
                    Node* newNode = (Node*) malloc(sizeof(Node));
                    if(newNode == NULL){
                                       printf("erreur d'allocation dynamique \n");
                                       exit(1);
                    }
                    newNode->left =  newNode->right = NULL;
                    newNode->value = value;
                    newNode->data = key;
                    precedant->left = newNode;
                    bst->size++;
                    return true;
                    }
            else{
                    Node* newNode = (Node*) malloc(sizeof(Node));
                    if(newNode == NULL){
                                       printf("erreur d'allocation dynamique \n");
                                       exit(1);
                    }

                    newNode->left =  newNode->right = NULL;
                    newNode->value = value;
                    newNode->data = key;
                    precedant->right = newNode;
                    bst->size++;
                    return true;

            }

        }
        return false;
}
```

Comment: The data type has no impact on whether or not you can use recursion.  Doing this with a set of while loops will be unpleasant, messy, and difficult to read.  Why is recursion off the table?

Comment: Is this a balanced search tree?

Comment: Unrelated, but you aren't doing `bst->size++` if the root is `NULL`

Comment: no isn't a balanced search tree it's binary search tree

Comment: tree* newBST(int comparison_fn_t(const void *, const void *)){

 tree* tree = (tree*) malloc(sizeof(tree));
    if(tree == NULL){
        printf("erreur d'allocation dynamic \n");
        exit(1);
    }
 tree->root = NULL;
 tree->comp = comparison_fn_t;
 tree->size = 0 ;
 return tree;
}      @AjayBrahmakshatriya

Comment: Recursion would be easier. In a loop you have to ensure not to use a freed Node, and there is an easy O(n^2) solution, or you could create an array that contains all nodes to be freed.

Comment: i want to delete all nodes in the tree

Comment: And why not using recursivity?

Comment: @RingØ look at the parameter how take the function freeTree is pointer to tree not Node

Comment: @RingØ with  a loop  i tried it but that doesn't work have you an idea

Comment: Added an answer that should clarify the recursion process.

Comment: yes i know but in this case i should change the prototype of my function it will take The [Node] as a parmater ? @RingØ

Comment: No. Keep the function signature as it is. Add the `freeNode` function above the `freeTree` function. And set `freeTree` body as shown in the answer.

Comment: Presumably, you can do this iteratively with a BFS (breadth-first search) and a queue of nodes to be deleted.  Presumably, the `TreeContent` parameter indicates whether the data pointed at by the `data ` and `value` members should be deleted too.  But we probably shouldn't have to presume; the question should describe what the requirements are more clearly.

Answer (score 1):

*edit* You don't want to use recursion because the `freeTree` function doesn't take a `Node` argument. In this case, you can remove that restriction by creating another function that is recursive, called initially by `freeTree`.

```
void freeTree(Tree* tree, bool TreeContent){
    if(tree->root != NULL){
        freeNode(tree->root);
        tree->root = NULL;
    }
}
```

The new `freeNode` could look like

```
void freeNode(Node *node) {
    if (node->left) freeNode(node->left);
    if (node->right) freeNode(node->right);
    free(node);
}
```

Note that `freeNode` intent is to free the whole tree (otherwise the parent element's left or right [or root] would have to be set to NULL).

Comment: and the second parameter TreeContent what will you do with it ?

Comment: @MJCPHCPH `treeContent`? No idea. Did you explain its role?

Comment: Given that the requirement is to avoid recursion, a recursive solution seems off-target.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler According to comments, OP couldn't do a recursive version because the freeTree function was not taking a Node argument. Then I suggested to use two functions, one being recursive.

Comment: OK; that's a different way of interpreting the 'no recursion' statement.  It makes sense.  Exercises that get asked here often proscribe the use of certain features (such as recursion), which was how I interpreted it.  The issue could go either way.

Answer (score 1):

Your requirement is that you don't want to use recursion.

Any kind of traversal is not possible in `O(n)` time without use of a stack/queue (implicitly or explicitly). So we will use a stack (made using an array) and use it to delete all the nodes.

I understand that you have the size of the BST known, so you can create an array of appropriate size as -

```
struct Node* stack[bst->size];
int top = -1;
```

This stack will hold all the elements to be processed.

We will first add the root to the stack -

```
if(bst->root)
    stack[++top] = bst->root;
```

Now we need to process all the nodes in the tree using a loop -

```
while(top>=0){
    //Pop one node - 
    struct Node* node = stack[top--];
    //Add its children to the stack;
    if(node->left)
        stack[++top] = node->left;
    if(node->right)
        stack[++top] = node->right;
    // Now free the node as 
    free(node);
}
```

That is all, one by one each node will be added to the stack and the stack will become empty when all the nodes are done.

Also as a side note, in your insert function you need to do `bst->size++` in the `if(bst->root == NULL)` branch. Else your size will be one less than actual number of nodes.

Comment: It *is* possible to solve that problem without a stack/queue. It's just expensive ( O(n^2) ).

Comment: @RingØ yes, you can rearrange the tree into a straight linked list and then free it. Maybe I should mention "in On(n) time" with my statement that a stack is required.